# Invariant violation element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)

Tags: react-native

For school we have to build an App in React-Native that can communicate and get data from sensors, but because of this error I can not proceed and have no clue what's wrong.

From looking around on stackoverflow and google I've come to the conclusion that it has to be a faulty import, but I don't know which one it is.

Invariant violation: element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

```
import React from 'react';
import { ScrollView, Text, Container, StyleSheet, View, Dimensions, Button } 
from 'react-native';
import { ExpoLinksView } from '@expo/samples';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
```

I hope someone can help me with the problem.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think the problem is in the render method of your component, please provide the code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to import something that does not exist from that package. There's no `Container` export from react-native.